# Magento - header slider not rotating images

Tags: magento

summary of problem. 
When multiple images are uploaded and referenced in the header slider - only the first image will appear, it will not cycle through them at all.

I am using iosslider through magento

```
<!-- slider container -->
<div class="iosslider"><!-- slider -->
<div class="slider"><!-- slides -->
<div class="slide"><a href="{{store url='womens'}}"><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/eg_mainheader.jpg"}}" alt="" data-srcx2="{{media url="wysiwyg/eg_mainheader@x2.jpg"}}" /></a></div>
<div class="slide"><a href="{{store url='#'}}"><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/eg_mainheader_men.jpg"}}" alt="" data-srcx2="{{media url="wysiwyg/eg_mainheader_men@x2.jpg"}}" /></a></div>
</div>
</div>
```

There is my current coding for the static block.

Our URL is earthgrownclothing.com - it is currently displaying both images at once.

and here are the setting for the slider on magento backend

Enabled: Yes
Auto Slide: Yes
Auto Slide Timer: 5000
auto slide trans timer: 750

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following:

- Install firebug in firefox browser and open website in firefox.
- Press f12, when firebug window is opened, click on console link.
- Refresh page.
  There must be some js error in console. Just fix that error and your slider will be alive again. :)

Comment: Followed your instructions and set the console to display Javascript errors/warnings - We have a plethora of them. 
The peculiar thing is that we have the slider up on two sites (one being our active site the other being our test) and they are both experiencing the same problem but displaying different issues.
Our main site is displaying only warnings whereas our test is displaying errors. 
Not sure what induced that